# SSRS - How to have two fields with same name in a dataset?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

In my xml dataset, I've two fields with the same name coming from two different tables. How can I use both fields in the field list?

Answer (score 1):

You can't - you'll need to rename one of them.

If you think about it, it makes no sense to have two fields with the same name in one dataset...it would be impossibly ambiguous, you wouldn't be able reliably fetch the data that you need because when you refer to that field it would be impossible to tell which one you meant.

Comment: That is correct, but can I qualify it with table name or something? I need both fields and I can't change field names in the database since it is from the ERP provider. Is there a way to define aliases etc.?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using stored procedures then you can give two different alias names to fields with same name.

Comment: I'm using XML datasource, not stored procedures.